# Remove x axis padding from container-fluid without horizontal scroll Boostrap 5

Tags: background-image, bootstrap-5, padding, bootstrap-grid

I have an image that should be full width at the top of a screen. I've removed padding left and right using px-0 but this has affected the page. I am now able to move around the page with the cursor. I do not want that to be the case

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img src="~/images/banners/group_full.png" alt="Image of a group of people" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides adding Bootstrap class `px-0` to the `container-fluid`, you also need to add `mx-0` to the `row` and `px-0` to the `col-12`.

Generally speaking, Bootstrap adds margins and paddings to all elements. In case you have a similar problem in the future, always check margins and paddings of all elements (`container-fluid`, `row`, `col`, etc.).

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row d-none d-md-block mx-0">
      <div class="col-12 px-0">
        <img src="~/images/banners/group_full.png" alt="Image of a group of people" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```